# Poor Quality Using Sip Api in Android

Tags: java, android, sip

So i tested the SipDemo on Two Phone , Galaxy s2 i9100G and Xperia Arc S , Galaxy s 2 is running  Jelly Bean and The Arc S ICS 4.0, Everything work well but Quality and volume is very poor i pretty cant Hear the User voice and there many noise , Source code is same as SipDemo , Is is a Codec Problem or is there any Solutions ? ,

Thanks

Comment: define "very poor". what is you element of comparison ?

Comment: Very poor mean the Call is made with success and Both Phone are Connected , but Volume is Very Very Low i Cant Hear anything unless i put my phone sticking to the ear , ther is even not a comparaison to do , this is just Unusable

Comment: did you try to change the volume ?

Comment: Music , Ringtone Volume set to Max. , and even if i put the phone sticked on my ear , it Like a Dead Jack 3.5 Line Quality is poor and Volume , on 100 i would like to say ... 5/100

Answer (score 1):

user1839514
You may need to verify which codec is being negotiated (in SDP) and used and provide more details about the connection. (Wifi vs 3g)
If possible check device resource utilization to isolate:
1) Codec problem (High quality codec resulting in High Bandwidth)
2) Connection problem (Network, packet loss, high jitter, latency)
3) Resource utilization (CPU, memory, i/o)

Comment: Ok so Firstly , Thanks you for your Answer , so How i can Check wich Codec is being negociated , you mean where i created my Sip account (linphone) ? , Both Phone are connected using Wifi with a very good signal , i dont know wich codecs are Used , iam new to Sip Developpement , CPU Utilisation ? nothing wrong , and Source code is exactly Same as SipDemo i didnt changed Anything

Comment: Edit : Volume set to max and uncheck 'Link Media Volume ...' and now , sound is 'Ok' on the Galaxy S2 , but its laggy , eg. : i say '1,2,3,4' i hear '1,2,3,4  1,2,3,4  1,2,3,4 ...' its laggy , but on the arc s Volume is still very Low